# Bio comes up when the visitor clicks on a picture

Tags: customization, images

On this page: http://creaturecomfortspetsitting.com/meet-the-team/ I'd like to make it so that when the visitor clicks on a image of a pet sitter the bio appears and when it's not clicked on it is just the picture and the Name/Title. Is this possible? Right now I'm using the "Blurb" module in Divi.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've found this useful article explaining the solution to your issue:
https://ayanize.com/snippets/how-to-use-divi-builder-blurb-module-as-a-toggle-to-display-or-hide-content/

I hope this information will be helpful to you.

Have a nice day.